How can I trigger pull refresh in flutter without calling refresh function
I am currently using the pull_to_refresh package in flutter and code looks something like this
final RefreshController refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: true);


SmartRefresher(
 controller: refreshController,
 onRefresh: (){
     // my refresh function
 },
 enablePullDown: true,
 scrollController: scrollController,
 child:ListView()
)

I tried using the command
refreshController.requestRefresh(needCallback: false);

but it does not show the loader on the top of the screen.
I need a solution that can show the loader at the top of the screen without calling the actual refresh function.

Couldn't reproduce. When calling refreshController.requestRefresh(needCallback: false);, it shows the loader and the onRefresh is not getting called.

It works for me when I declared the refresh controller as RefreshController() without initialRefresh is true. Keep in mind that calling requestRefresh if its loading will not do anything. Also, are you sure you called refreshController.requestRefresh(needCallback: false); in the right place? For example, I called on a button's action and it works fine.

FYI, Flutter has built-in refresh indicator solution: RefreshIndicator

I called the refreshController.requestRefresh(needCallback:false); in a floating action button. I also declared RefreshController() without initialRefresh:true and it still does not work.
what version of pull_to_refresh are you using

Make your onRefresh method async type. It should show the loader.
onRefresh: () async{
    // manually waiting a bit if your data fetching method ins't an async
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    
    refreshController.requestRefresh(needCallback: false);
  }

